# Проблема DependencyProperties: биндинг к RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

Занимаюсь wpf недавно. Начал изучать MVVM и все к нему прилагающееся.

Начал биндить значения к RichTextBox, но это казалась не совсем тривиальная задача. Погуглив, я нашел, что проблема решается через создание нового пользовательского контрола, в который добавляется DependencyProperty. биндить значение получилось.
Но, если я меняю сам текст в richtextbox, то значение в прикрепленном элементе не меняется. Опять погуглив, нашел вариант решения, но он выдает ошибку.

Код usercontrol:

```
public string Document
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(DocumentProperty); }
    set { SetValue(DocumentProperty, value); }
}

public static DependencyProperty DocumentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Document",
    typeof(string), typeof(EmailCreator),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
    {
        AffectsArrange = false,
        PropertyChangedCallback = CallBack
    });

private static void CallBack(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
{
    try
    {
        int lastPos = 0;
        var content = dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue as string;
        var emailCreator = dependencyObject as EmailCreator;
        var richTextBox = emailCreator.Viewer;

        //Очищаем данные из документа
        richTextBox.Document.Blocks.Clear();

        var paragraph = new Paragraph();
        paragraph.Inlines.Add(content);

        //Отображаем собщение
        richTextBox.Document.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}

private void RichTextBoxOnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs textChangedEventArgs)
{
    var s = (sender as RichTextBox);

    var text = new TextRange(
        // TextPointer to the start of content in the RichTextBox.
        s.Document.ContentStart,
        // TextPointer to the end of content in the RichTextBox.
        s.Document.ContentEnd
        );

    if(text.Text != "")
    Document = text.Text;
}


private static void RequestNavigateHandler(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Process.Start(e.Uri.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}

public EmailCreator()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Viewer.TextChanged += RichTextBoxOnTextChanged;
}
```

Но я получаю ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понимаю почему, вылетает эта ошибка, но не понимаю как её исправить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, у вас очевидная бесконечная рекурсия. Изменение в VM ведёт к вызову callback'а, который меняет `RichTextBox`, который вызывает `RichTextBoxOnTextChanged`, который меняет значение `UserControl.Document`, что снова приводит к вызову callback'а.

Простой метод побороть это — попробуйте на время обновления `RichTextBox` выставить флаг, который блокирует действие callback'а.

```
static void CallBack(
    DependencyObject dependencyObject,
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
{
    ((EmailCreator)dependencyObject).OnDocumentPropertyChanged();
}

bool updatingDocument = false;
void OnDocumentPropertyChanged()
{
    updatingDocument = true;
    try
    {
        //Очищаем данные из документа
        Viewer.Document.Blocks.Clear();

        var paragraph = new Paragraph();
        paragraph.Inlines.Add(content);

        //Отображаем собщение
        Viewer.Document.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        updatingDocument = true;
    }
}

void RichTextBoxOnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs textChangedEventArgs)
{
    if (updatingDocument)
        return;

    var s = (sender as RichTextBox);

    var text = new TextRange(
        // TextPointer to the start of content in the RichTextBox.
        s.Document.ContentStart,
        // TextPointer to the end of content in the RichTextBox.
        s.Document.ContentEnd
        );

    if(text.Text != "")
        Document = text.Text;
}
```

---

Но на самом деле проблема глубже. `RichTextBox` не просто так нельзя забиндить к VM. Дело в том, что контент у него, в отличие от всех остальных контролов, сложный, и правильный тип VM, представляющий документ с форматированием, не так просто создать.

Поэтому более правильный подход был бы, наверное, такой: создать кастомную модель (или VM) документа и выполнять привязку `RichTextBox`'а к ней вручную.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Про рекурсию я понял. Решил проблему как раз тем методом, что Вы предложили. 
Но как то это костылем на мой взгляд отдает((
А можно про более правильный подход подробнее? Если есть возможность с примером

Comment: @Vyacheslav: Да, некий костыль, но что ж делать? RichTextBox не предназначен для Binding'а, судя по всему.

Comment: @Vyacheslav: ну, я не смогу так сходу написать разумный пример модели документа. Там нужен для каждого куска текста шрифт, размер, атрибуты наподобие жирный/наклонный/верхний индекс/... и всё такое.

Comment: @Vyacheslav: Ага, вот есть идея по поводу правильной модели: XAML! Вот код: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2641774/276994

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и за ссылку. Осталось только не понятно зачем так было усложнять работу с RichTextBox

Comment: @Vyacheslav: Пожалуйста! Мне кажется, именно из-за того, чтобы не навязывать подходящую VM. По сути, для простых контролов (`TextBox`, и т. п.) VM очевидна: строка. А `RichTextBox` по логике скорее большой, сложный `UserControl`, вот и VM ему нужна сложная. В общем, я понимаю авторов WPF (но не поддерживаю: ну сделали бы VM, ну да, сложно, что поделать?).